# How to create a bar plot that is unique for each category in a dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am using a dataset on video games and am trying to create a bar plot that will display the total sales by platform. Unfortunately, when I plot the bar each individual bar just takes the name of the platform one after another in the dataset, instead of each unique gaming platform. Below is my code:

```py
ax[0,1].bar(df.Platform, df["Global_Sales"])
ax[0,1].set_xticklabels(df.Platform, rotation = 90)
ax[0,1].set_ylabel("Global Sales (millions)")
ax[0,1].set_title("Global Sales by Platform")
```

Any advice on how I can get my bar plot to show each platform individually?

[image: image of dataframe head]
[image: image of bar plot]

Also I get this error at the bottom of my code any help would be appreciated:

```
UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  ax[0,1].set_xticklabels(df.Platform, rotation = 90)
```

Comment: sounds like you want something like `df.groupby('Platform')['Global_Sales'].sum().plot.bar(ax=ax[0,1])`

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. If you expect to get code as an answer, you may want to provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, do not provide screenshots of your data but prepare a toy example with random data that is formatted just as your original data